# read arrays in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I need some help of solving that issue: I have 5 different voltage values that change every single tick time - that mean every single moment. I need to sort them and after they been sorted I want to go to another matrix(like this one at the bottom) and to pull out(read) specific column from it, for every state pre define(timing that I am designing..) That mechanism change every single states/moment. How can I do this ?

The Matrix look like(and could be greater...):

```
 0     0     0     1     1     1...
 0     1     1     0     0     1...
 1     0     1     0     1     0...
 1     1     0     1     0     0...

..     ..    ..    ..    ..    ..
```

Thanks, Henry

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood it correctly. So I will edit my answer after you make your question a bit more clear.

I see two separate things:

1. Reading 5 voltage values which change at each step. You want to sort these values. To do this you can use the sort function of matlab. It is really easy to use and you can look at it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?refresh=true).
2. This is the part I didn't understand well. After sorting the voltage readings what do you want to do with the matrix ? If you want to access just a specific column of the matrix and save it in a variable you can do it in this way. Let's assume you have a matrix A which is N x N, if you want to access the 10th column of the matrix and store it in a variable called `column10` you will do something like: `column10 = A(:,10)`

I hope this will help you but let me know if this is what you wanted and I will edit my answer according to it.

Fab.